# Why did not save multiple images with controller route return?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, controller

In my Laravel app I have form to save multiple images to save uploads table, my form as following,

```
<form method="post" action="{{url('form')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
            {{csrf_field()}}
<div class="form-group row required">
            <div class="field" align="left" >
            <h3>Upload  images</h3>
            <input type="file" class="files" name="files[]" multiple />
            <input type="file" class="files" name="files[]" multiple />
            <input type="file" class="files" name="files[]" multiple />
            <input type="file" class="files" name="files[]" multiple />
            </div>
</div>
```

and controller store function is,

```
$photos = $request->file('files');

        if (!is_array($photos)) {
            $photos = [$photos];
        }

        if (!is_dir($this->photos_path)) {
            mkdir($this->photos_path, 0777);
        }

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($photos); $i++) {
            $photo = $photos[$i];
            $name = sha1(date('YmdHis') . str_random(30));
            $save_name = $name . '.' . $photo->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $resize_name = $name . str_random(2) . '.' . $photo->getClientOriginalExtension();

            Image::make($photo)
                ->resize(250, null, function ($constraints) {
                    $constraints->aspectRatio();
                })
                ->save($this->photos_path . '/' . $resize_name);

            $photo->move($this->photos_path, $save_name);

            $upload = new Upload();
            $upload->filename = $save_name;
            $upload->resized_name = $resize_name;
            $upload->original_name = basename($photo->getClientOriginalName());
            $upload->vehicle_id = $vehicle->id;
            $upload->save();
            return redirect()->route('categories.categorypost')->with('info','Your Advertisment has been created successfully');
        }
    }
```

but when I attach 4 images in above form. it is saving only one image. that attach to first input file. why other images are not saving to table. but when i remove return following codes

```
return redirect()->route('categories.categorypost')->with('info','Your Advertisment has been created successfully');
```

then I can save all images. but I need above controller return and saving all images. how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your redirect is inside the for loop that iterates the images and saves them, you have to put the redirect after the for loop, otherwise you will be redirected after the first image is saved:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($photos); $i++) {
    $photo = $photos[$i];
    $name = sha1(date('YmdHis') . str_random(30));
    $save_name = $name . '.' . $photo->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $resize_name = $name . str_random(2) . '.' . $photo->getClientOriginalExtension();

    Image::make($photo)
        ->resize(250, null, function ($constraints) {
            $constraints->aspectRatio();
        })
        ->save($this->photos_path . '/' . $resize_name);

    $photo->move($this->photos_path, $save_name);

    $upload = new Upload();
    $upload->filename = $save_name;
    $upload->resized_name = $resize_name;
    $upload->original_name = basename($photo->getClientOriginalName());
    $upload->vehicle_id = $vehicle->id;
    $upload->save();
}
return redirect()->route('categories.categorypost')->with('info','Your Advertisment has been created successfully');
```